# Smoothen the gradient after filling by content-aware

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, fill, image-editing

May I know how to make the gradient color looks more natural after filling by the content-awareness on the left?

I tried to use a Stamp tool, but it does not work as expected. :(

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **Patch tool** for such areas.

**1)** Select the patch tool from the tools panel.

[image]

**2)** Make the selection of the area you wish to edit. (Make sure to go with small areas as it will lead to a better result.)

[image]

**3)** Drag the selected area to its left or right to patch and heal the selected area.

**4)** Repeat these steps for the remaining parts and you will get the desired result as shown below.

[image]

** COMPARISION:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Make a rectangular selection from top to bottom around the area
- Apply a **Feather** to the selection, around 20px
- Menu **Filter** > **Noise** > **Dust & Scratches**

[image: VIDEO]

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: If I still can see a bit of the line, is that mean my feather effect is not strong enough?

Comment: I set the feather in the copy/paste image from your question, I don't know the real PPI of the original image. If it's a high resolution image, increase the feather.

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid needing the answer at all, don't make that line in the first place...

Don't feather the selection edge before using content-aware fill, especially on such an 'easy' fill as that & it won't make that line at all.

Exaggerated feathering...

[image]

No feathering...

[image]